# How to create a folder to further create .csv files in?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a problem creating a SUBMIT folder within my default package to create the .csv files into and I am unsure if I am able to do that manually for the project or if they must be created through my program in order to work.

```
import java.io.*;

public class HW01 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    // Create a 1D array to hold header labels
    String headerLabels[] =  
        {"COURSE ID", "TEAM ID", "STUDENT FIRST NAME",
         "STUDENT LAST NAME", "STUDENT ID", "ASSIGNMENT ID",
         "DATE SUBMITTED", "TIME SUBMITTED", "SUBMITTED BY"
        };

    // Create a 2D array to hold header values
    String headerValues[][] =
        {
        {"CMPS280-02", "Invokers01", "James", "Brown", "w0479045", "H01", "8/25/2017", "1:14PM", "James Brown"},
        {"CMPS280-01", "Winners03", "Jacob", "Harley", "w0389342", "H03", "8/23/2017", "7:24PM", "Jacob Harley"},
        {"SE101-02", "CodeIt00", "Keith", "Dillinger", "w0782345", "S04", "8/25/2017", "1:23AM", "Keith Dillinger"}
        };

    // Array Loop to be used later
    //for (int i = 0; i < headerValues.length; i++){
        //for (int j = 0; j < headerValues[i].length; j++){
      }
          }

    // Create new .csv file and store in SUBMIT folder
    String path = "SUBMIT/"+headerValues[0][0]+"_"+headerValues[0][5]+"_"+headerValues[0][1]+"_"+headerValues[0][4]+".csv";
    File file = new File(path);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it the old way. The main thing that you missed is to create the directory if it doesn't exist. And, close the writer when you are done with it.

```
package createcsvfile;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CreateCsvFile {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        // Create a 1D array to hold header labels
        String headerLabels[] =  
            {"COURSE ID", "TEAM ID", "STUDENT FIRST NAME",
             "STUDENT LAST NAME", "STUDENT ID", "ASSIGNMENT ID",
             "DATE SUBMITTED", "TIME SUBMITTED", "SUBMITTED BY"
            };

        // Create a 2D array to hold header values
        String headerValues[][] =
            {
            {"CMPS280-02", "Invokers01", "James", "Brown", "w0479045", "H01", "8/25/2017", "1:14PM", "James Brown"},
            {"CMPS280-01", "Winners03", "Jacob", "Harley", "w0389342", "H03", "8/23/2017", "7:24PM", "Jacob Harley"},
            {"SE101-02", "CodeIt00", "Keith", "Dillinger", "w0782345", "S04", "8/25/2017", "1:23AM", "Keith Dillinger"}
            };

        // Array Loop to be used later
        // for (int i = 0; i < headerValues.length; i++){
        // for (int j = 0; j < headerValues[i].length; j++){

        String path1 = "SUBMIT";    
        // Create new .csv file and store in SUBMIT folder
        String path2 = "SUBMIT/"+headerValues[0][0]+"_"+headerValues[0][5]+"_"+headerValues[0][1]+"_"+headerValues[0][4]+".csv";

        try {
            File file1 = new File(path1);
            if (!file1.isDirectory()) {
               file1.mkdir();
            }        
            File file = new File(path2);        
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `java.nio.file` package(which is the preferred way for working with files starting with Java7):

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path pathToFile = Paths.get("dirname/filename.csv");
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(pathToFile.getParent());
            Files.createFile(pathToFile);
        } catch( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `java.io` package:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("dirname", "filename.csv");
        new File(file.getParent()).mkdirs();
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```